# Elegant way of using masks in Tensors/Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

Say I have a tensor(This question also reffers to numpy arrays) `A` of size `N`, that contains values from range `(0,D-1)`. I also have another tensor `B` of size `(N,D)`.

Now what I want to do, is to change each row of `B`, in the corresponding column of the value of same row in `A`. I.E. `A[0] = 2, A[1] = 3`, so I want to change `B[0,2]` and `B[1,3]`.

I've managed to solve it like this:

```
B[torch.ones((N,D)) * torch.arange(D) == torch.ones((N,D)) * A.reshape(-1,1)] = newVal
```

I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution to achieve this. Something like:

```
B[:,A] = newVal
```

Obviously this doesn't work..

Comment: `B[torch.arange(N), A] = newVal`?

Comment: Why is it different from `B[:,A] = newVal` ? @bb1

Comment: `B[:, A]` selects the whole columns with indices coming from `A`. `B[torch.arange(N), A]` uses fancy indexing. It selects elements where the row number comes from `torch.arange(N)` and the column number comes from `A`. So the selected elements are `B[0, A[0]]`, `B[1, A[1]]` etc.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it worked. You can post it as answer and I'll accept @bb1